# Xcode Crashes when working on UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, uitableview

Why does my Xcode hangs and start using up **Mac's RAM** which I later have to Force Close from my **Activity Monitor** whenever I try to use that aspect of `UITableView` or `UITableViewController` properties unless I restart my Mac. And once I restart and change from for instance `Dynamic properties` to `Static Cells` I can’t change back. It’ll be crashing all the way unless I restart the Mac again

[image: TableView]

Comment: information is not enough any screen shot or sample code?

Comment: Updated. This is just an xcode bug. Not a code problem